# Pig Latin Program

Tags: c++, string

I'm not getting errors, but the output is incorrect. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I can only use functions from string library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;



int main() {


    string message, pig_message;
    getline(cin, message);

    unsigned int x = message.find_first_of("aeiou");
    if (message[x] == 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u' ) {
        pig_message = message + "yay";
        cout << pig_message;

    }
    else if (!(message[x] == 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u' )) {
        pig_message = message.substr(1) + message[0] + "ay";
        cout << pig_message;
    }



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: `message[x] == 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u'` does *not* mean what you think it means.

Comment: It should be `if (message[x] == 'a' || message[x] == 'e' || ... ) {`.

Comment: Plus, assuming I understand your meaning correctly, you probably just need an else, not an else if.

Comment: … Also, the `else if (…)` could be just `else`.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison statement is incorrect. 
Make sure your function is actually iterating through the letters, and that you're concatenating the strings correctly.

So:
unsigned int x = message.find_first_of("aeiou"); // Returns the first match 
if(message[x] == 'a' || message[x] == 'e'...) // Currently your code reads as only checking for a.

Think of it as IF message[x] = a, IF e, IF i
vs 
if message[x] = a, IF message[x] = i

What does your code do after it finds a match? 
pig_message = message + 'yay' would add "yay" to the whole message string.
It would then print it out and move on, without doing anything to the other vowels.

I'm new to C++ myself but that's how I've understood your code.

It might be better to go through the whole input string one letter at a time in a for loop with your if else statements to add the strings inside the loop.

Comment: Detail your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first if statement is always true. You should change it to

```
if (message[x] == 'a' || message[x] == 'e' || message[x] == 'i' || message[x] == 'o' || message[x] == 'u' ) {
```

Also, you could change the `else if (...) {` line to just

```
else {
```

if you want it to be executed every time the first if statement is not true.